# Redshift Default Permissions for new tables in schema

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-redshift

I am using a service to generate tables in our redshift warehouse. It drops tables in a schema and rebuilds them daily. I altered the default privileges to give `user1` read access to it but it isn't working.

Running this from the redshift docs:

```
select pg_get_userbyid(d.defacluser) as user, 
n.nspname as schema, 
case d.defaclobjtype when 'r' then 'tables' when 'f' then 'functions' end 
as object_type, 
array_to_string(d.defaclacl, ' + ')  as default_privileges 
from pg_catalog.pg_default_acl d 
left join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = d.defaclnamespace;
```

Gives me this line for the schema in question:

```
+-------------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+
|    user     |      schema      | object_type | default_privileges  |
+-------------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| mysuperuser | schemainquestion | tables      | user1=r/mysuperuser |
+-------------+------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

This is the command I ran to alter the privileges:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA schemainquestion GRANT SELECT ON  TABLES to user1;
```

I verified with `has_schema_privilege` that `user1` has `USAGE` permissions on the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement as the user that will create the tables, or add a `FOR ROLE` clause for that user.